# Selenium Click is not working in Windows10 IE11

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

We are using Selenium with C#,But Selenium click functionality is not working in Windows 10 IE11,If I am using Javascriptexecutor then its working,
But My requirement is not to use Javascriptexecutor

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)seleniumuiDriver.webDr).ExecuteScript("return document.querySelectorAll(arguments[0])[0].click();", identifier.Split('$')[0]);
```

When I am using Javascriptexecutor then I cant able to use ID,Xpath,Name.I can able to use only CssSelector. Is there any way to work with in IE11 
windows 10 without Javascriptexecutor

Selenium Version:2.49

Programing Language:C#

Comment: @RyanWilson The IE driver sucks because the developer who’s responsible for most of the code is not terribly competent, I suppose. However, I know that he’s always willing to participate in a discussion about specific ideas to make it better. Have you tried engaging the (entirely volunteer and unpaid) development team?

Comment: @JimEvans I heard that is was not particularly good because of Microsoft, not the development team involved with Selenium. In fact, pretty much every other driver that has come from the Selenium team has been top notch.

Comment: @JimEvans I'd like to apologize for the comment, I know what it's like to work hard on something and have someone not appreciate it. I wasn't thinking about that when I wrote it. I know you work hard to help provide a good product that as you pointed out is free of charge. As stated in my previous comment, I believe some of the issues that I experienced with the IE driver were more related to Microsoft not working with the Selenium team rather than any kind of incompetence in the Selenium dev team. I would like to say thank you Jim for all the hard work you and the team have done.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with python and selenium. My workaround was setting a variable using find_element_by//whatever you want and calling it in the javascript. That way you can identify the element however you like, and javascript will still be able to read it.

here is an example of what I'm talking about (again this is python, but the syntax switch shouldn't be that much of an issue:

```
nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'2')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].click();", nextPage)
```

Comment: Is there any solution without using javascriptexecutor?

Comment: If the element isn’t visible I don’t think so. I could be wrong but it’s always been because the web element wasn’t visible when I’ve had to pass it into Javascript. This is more times than not on platforms that try to impede you from scripting and automating (especially social media).